# Sharepoint Active Directory Users/Groups

Tags: user-profile, security, groups, directory

I'm currently testing some things in SharePoint (Trial/Developer mode).

Current setup:
SharePoint 2013 Server
Domain Controller with 2008 R2 (Active Directory).

I've configured the SharePoint option "Active Directory Import" with the idea that i could add users or groups to my sites. So for example my SharePoint Editors security group can edit things at one specific site. Unfortunately i cant find any active directory users at all.

When i'm at: `Application Management > Manage service applications > User Profile Service Application > Manage User Profiles |` I CAN find the active directory users here. I also can find the Security Groups at if i want to add a SharePoint Audience

but i can't add them when i'm at:

`Site Settings > Site Permissions or People Groups`.

I really want to add my security group to a specific SharePoint group or just a security group directly added to SharePoint so i can give specific policies to the groups.